# How to guess image mime type?

Tags: python, image, cross-platform, mime

How can I guess an image's mime type, in a cross-platform manner, and without any external libraries?

Comment: Why is not using external libraries a requirement?

Comment: Cause when your case is simple, there is no need to load heavy full-duty libraries if a small snippet can do the job.

Comment: An external library might do it exactly the same way that you end up doing in your own code. By using a light-weight external library you avoid writing code and potentially introducing bugs. I can even imagine something based on a C library (such as libmagic) being faster and lighter than something written in plain Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know in advance that you only need to handle a limited number of file formats you can use the [imghdr.what](http://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html#imghdr.what) function.

Comment: Dind't know about `imghdr`. It's great.

Answer (score 3):

I've checked the popular image types' format on wikipedia, and tried to make a signature:

```
def guess_image_mime_type(f):
    '''
    Function guesses an image mime type.
    Supported filetypes are JPG, BMP, PNG.
    '''
    with open(f, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read(11)
    if data[:4] == '\xff\xd8\xff\xe0' and data[6:] == 'JFIF\0':
        return 'image/jpeg'
    elif data[1:4] == "PNG":
        return 'image/png'
    elif data[:2] == "BM":
        return 'image/x-ms-bmp'
    else:
        return 'image/unknown-type'
```

Comment: Instead of looking up the signatures manually you could reimplement part of libmagic by parsing the [magic file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic)

Comment: Had to add 'b' before the binary string comparison to make it work

Answer (score 1):

If you can rely on the file extension you can use the [mimetypes.guess_type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type) function. Note that you may get different results on different platforms, but I would still call it cross-platform.

Comment: As you said, it's useful if you can rely on the file extension. I used few web services lately that send you the raw image data without a filename, so it'd be useless in such cases.

Comment: Does not support `image/bmp`