# How to test if a webpage is an image

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, urllib

Sorry that the title wasn't very clear, basically I have a list with a whole series of url's, with the intention of downloading the ones that are pictures. Is there anyway to check if the webpage is an image, so that I can just skip over the ones that arent?

Thanks in advance

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644880/how-to-guess-image-mime-type

Answer (score 6):

You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module. Make a head request and check the content type. Head request will not download the response body.

```
import requests
response = requests.head(url)
print response.headers.get('content-type')
```

Comment: you can [get Content-Type header using only stdlib](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29047487/4279)

Answer (score 4):

There is no reliable way. But you could find a solution that might be "good enough" in your case.

You could look at the file extension if it is present in the url e.g., `.png`, `.jpg` could indicate an image:

```
>>> import os
>>> name = url2filename('http://example.com/a.png?q=1')
>>> os.path.splitext(name)[1]
'.png'
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.guess_type(name)[0]
'image/png'
```

where [`url2filename()` function is defined here](https://gist.github.com/zed/c2168b9c52b032b5fb7d).

You could inspect `Content-Type` http header:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> r = urllib.request.urlopen(url) # make HTTP GET request, read headers
>>> r.headers.get_content_type()
'image/png'
>>> r.headers.get_content_maintype()
'image'
>>> r.headers.get_content_subtype()
'png'
```

You could check the very beginning of the http body for magic numbers indicating image files e.g., [jpeg may start with `b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0'`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) or:

```
>>> prefix = r.read(8)
>>> prefix # .png image
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n'
```

[As @pafcu suggested in the answer to the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14646324/4279), you could use [`imghdr.what()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html#imghdr.what):

```
>>> import imghdr
>>> imghdr.what(None, b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n')
'png'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mimetypes` https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/mimetypes.html

```
import urllib
from mimetypes import guess_extension

url="http://example.com/image.png"
source = urllib.urlopen(url)
extension = guess_extension(source.info()['Content-Type'])
print extension
```

this will return "png"

Comment: it won't work on Python 3 (the question has [tag:python-3.x] tag)

Comment: You can make it work if you fix the imports. Also, it is not clear why do you want to guess the file extension here. Content-Type is clear by itself: it even may have the word 'image' in it (you could extract it as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29047487/4279))