# python: image corrupted when downloading via urllib

Tags: python, html, image, http-headers, urllib

I have an old project which is downloading images via urllib.

Sometimes, the images which are downloaded are corrupted.

Take the below image for example,

https://images.allsaints.com/products/900/WO053N/2824/WO053N-2824-1.jpg

When I try to open it in Image Viewer, I get

```
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3c 0x21)
```

Turns out, it is an html file.

So, I read this answer,

[How to test if a webpage is an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047316/how-to-test-if-a-webpage-is-an-image)

So, I checked headers for this image,

```
>>> b = requests.get('https://images.allsaints.com/products/900/WO053N/2824/WO053N-2824-1.jpg')
>>> b.headers.get('content-type')
'image/jpeg'
```

It shows in the headers that it is an image/jpeg, but actually it is HTML page.

So, How can I properly check that whether a url is an image OR HTML?

Comment: Did you read all the answers in the question you linked to? Particularly the last one?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida turns out it was a problem due to headers, I set my request header(user-agent) and it worked.