# Saving Images as BLOB data to MySQL: som images are saved as "Not valid bitmap file"

Tags: mysql, image, bitmap, blob

I have a python script running the following task:
1,read an image URL, read the image
2,save this image to MySQL as BLOB data

After the task is completed,I checked mysql and found some problem. Most of the images were fine, however some images cannot be opened with image tool like "paint" in windows. It showed me the following error:

C:\Users\myimage.bin
Paint cannot read this file.
This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported.

Then I checked the encoded data for saved images in mysql, it seems that all the "bad images" strat with "0x4949BC" and all "good images" start with "0xFFD8FF". Does this difference tell us any information?

I'm new to database, could someone help me figure out what could be the problem? Could it be due to some mistake during image encoding/save process? Thank you very much!

Comment: There is not enough information here to provide an answer. Perhaps provide a snippet of code and some example URLs of "good" images and "bad" images.

Comment: I think those 0x4949 images might be TIFF, which Paint can't read. You could try opening them with the [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

Comment: Thank you @Kenney. GIMP is still being downloaded. But since you suggested,  I tried with windows photo viewer and it worked! So it might be due to the file format. However, the URL for those images are .jpg (e.g., https://a2.muscache.com/im/pictures/19366454/0014ad52_original.jpg?aki_policy=x_large).

Comment: Yes, that one is a JPG. You should probably save the file extension and/or the mime type with the blob (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644880/how-to-guess-image-mime-type)).

Comment: Many thanks Kenney!!!